# New thread or AsyncTask?

Tags: android

I have canvases on display and color of every canvas is defined by status ( I read from json file ). I need to periodically (on every 2 or 3 seconds ) read json file and refresh canvas status - color. My question is what to use to periodically read json: onether thread which is in while(true) loop aor do I need to use AsyncTask ? What is better solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

periodically ? I'd say - [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)